# split text file (Genome data) based on column values keeping header line

Tags: linux, unix, bioinformatics

I have a big genome data file (.txt) in the format below. I would like to split it based on chromosome column `chr1, chr2..chrX,chrY` and so forth keeping the header line in all splitted files. How can I do this using unix/linux command?

genome data

```
 variantId  chromosome   begin  end
    1            1          33223  34343
    2            2          44543  46444
    3            2          55566  59999 
    4            3          33445  55666
```

result

```
file.chr1.txt
variantId  chromosome   begin  end
1            1          33223  34343


file.chr2.txt
variantId  chromosome   begin  end
2            2          44543  46444
3            2          55566  59999 

file.chr3.txt
variantId  chromosome   begin  end
4            3          33445  55666
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service. You're expected to show an attempt to solve your problem, or failing that, at least an indication of which programming language you'd like to learn about and use. Can you update your Q with what you have tried, OR feel free to post a bounty, as then readers will be motivated to help you with your problem. Good luck.

Comment: `awk 'NR!=1 {print >"file.chr"$2".txt"}' "sourcefile.txt"` (note: this skips first line from sourcefile.txt and doesn't insert it into destionation files; copy header line yourself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this data for the human genome (i.e. always 46 chromosomes)?  If so, how's this:

```
for chr in $(seq 1 46)
do
    head -n1 data.txt >chr$chr.txt
done
awk 'NR != 1 { print $0 >>("chr"$2".txt") }' data.txt
```

(This is a second edit, based on @Sasha's comment above.)

Note that the parens around `("chr"$2".txt")` are apparently not needed on GNU awk, but they are on my OS X version of awk.

Comment: Thanks. However, I have chromosomes 1:21 and then X and Y chromoromes,so how does this code work with my data?

Comment: Then just change the first line to `for chr in $(seq 1 22) X Y`.  The for loop is only doing the header lines anyway, the awk line is doing the real work, and it will handle whatever is in the second column, whether it's a number or letter.